# Is there a more efficient way to collect elements from a single large 1-D array and place them in a single small 1-D array?

Tags: fortran, vectorization, fortran90, intel-fortran

**Simple description:** I have a big array(datatype is real64)`bigArray1` that is allocated and initialized with numbers in an unsorted manner. I create another small array `smallArray` with the same datatype as the big array.
Now, I'd like `smallArray` to contain a subset of `bigArray1` according to a mask(say `bigArray1 > 0.0d0`). This is easily achieved with the intrinsic:

```
smallArray = pack(bigArray1, bigArray1 > 0.0d0)
```

Now, a step further, say I have another `bigArray2` and I'd like `smallArray` to pick up elements from bigArray1 at indexes returned by an intersection of a mask on `bigArray1` and a different mask on `bigArray2`, I can do:

```
smallArray = pack(bigArray1, bigArray1 > 0.0d0 .and. bigArray2 < 0.0d0)
```

I think this method is vectorizable, since intel optrpt reported that it vectorized the line that contains `pack`

For larger arrays with about a million elements, I've found that my actual code consumes too much time and memory when it uses pack intrinsic. The do-loop algorithm seems to be faster but is not vectorizable due to dependencies.

**Minimal working example:**

```
program test
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  integer, parameter :: dp = real64
  real(dp), allocatable :: a(:), b(:), c(:)
  !dir$ attributes align:64 :: a
  !dir$ attributes align:64 :: b
  !dir$ attributes align:64 :: c

  allocate(a(1:10), b(1:10))
  a = [1.1_dp, 1.2_dp, 1.3_dp, 1.4_dp, 1.5_dp, 1.6_dp, 1.7_dp, 1.8_dp, 1.9_dp, 2.0_dp]
  b = [2.1_dp, 2.2_dp, 2.3_dp, 2.4_dp, 2.5_dp, 2.6_dp, 2.7_dp, 2.8_dp, 2.9_dp, 3.0_dp]

  write(*,*) 'a :', a
  write(*,*) 'b :', b
  c = pack(a, a >=1.2_dp .and. a < 1.9_dp .and. b >=2.3_dp .and. b < 2.6_dp )
  write(*,*) 'c :', c
  deallocate(a,b,c)

end program test
```

**With do loops:**

```
!Initialize number of elements in c to 0
n_elem_c = 0
!Count elements that satisfy both masks
do i = 1, 10
  if(a(i) >= 1.2_dp .and. a(i) < 1.9_dp &
  .and. b(i) >= 2.3_dp .and. b(i) < 2.6_dp) then

    n_elem_c = n_elem_c + 1

  end if
end do

allocate(c(1:n_elem_c))
id = 0
!Assign elements to c
do i = 1, 10
  if(a(i) >= 1.2_dp .and. a(i) < 1.9_dp &
  .and. b(i) >= 2.3_dp .and. b(i) < 2.6_dp) then

    id = id + 1
    c(id) = a(i)

  end if
end do
```

**Output:**

```
a :   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0
b :   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.0
c :   1.3  1.4  1.5
```

Is there an alternative to this algorithm that's vectorizable? Perhaps even faster? Or is this the only possible way to do it?

I hope I've been able to explain my problem. I've been a searcher so far on stackoverflow, this is my first question, so I humbly request the overlords to go gentle on me. If you require the actual use case of this algorithm, I can provide the snippet.

Comment: Do you care about parallelization? Or is this independent of other efforts that may include parallelization?

Comment: Well, actually this snippet is part of a sub-routine that is called inside an `!$omp parallel do schedule(runtime)` region. So I want it to be vectorized to make use of vector registers within a core.

Comment: Are `bigArray1` and `bigArray2` constrained to have the same size - which seems to be a necessary consequence of the example codes you've shown us ?  If so, you might achieve a more cache-friendly code by turning them into a rank 2 array and being careful about ordering.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes. `bigArray1` and `bigArray2` are always of the same size. Pardon my understanding, could you please elaborate more on your suggestion?